# Access PSObject property by name in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, psobject

For example I have a PSObject transaction with two properties: id and transactionName , so that it looks like:
transaction {
    id: 123
    transactionName : tranName1
}

and I want to return the id of the transaction if its name is tranName1.

It looks to me that in powershell scripts, we can simply do:

```
if $transaction.transactionName -eq tranName return $transaction.id
```

however in c# it will give error since it cannot recognize the property by name... any ideas how to do it in c#?

Comment: Possibly because the property name is `transactionName`?

Comment: @p.s.w.g even I corrected the name it won't work, because C# knows transaction as PSObject, which does not contain a member of "transactionName"...

Comment: There is no C# code posted. Anyway, just find the type, then [*look at the documentation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.aspx) for basic ideas of how to use it .. however, I suspect that using a correctly-typed "transaction" value to begin with would be more useful.

Comment: @pst Mike Shepard provided the solution to my answer :) thank you though for sharing :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
psobjectvariable.Properties["transactionName"].Value
```

Comment: I know this is an old reply but, what about subproperties, for example:     $transaction.transactionName.propertyA

Comment: @Roberto If `propertyA` is a PSObject you can do like this: `((PSObject)psobjectvariable.Properties["transactionName"].Value).Properties["propertyA"]`

Comment: @Patrick doesn't cast, please... You'll get an error. Try: `PSObject.AsPSObject`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's something that I didn't expect to work, but it did.

```
dynamic x = psobjectvariable;
Console.Write(x.transactionName);
```